# seqmentation fault at memory allocation

Tags: c++, memory-management, segmentation-fault

On start up my application will crash about %50 of the time with a segmentation fault at the following line of code:

```
float** temp = new float*[map_size];
```

The value of map_size is 513.

This crass never occurs in debug mode.  The application is fairly large now at 10,000 lines of code and has multiple threads running so I doubt posting any additional code will be of use. (I'm not sure what to post really)

Since this line of code is fairly straight forward I'm guessing that my error is elsewhere.  My best guess would be that somewhere else my program is overreaching allocated memory and then when I try to allocate more occasionally it clashes and causes the fault.  Is this a possible scenario?

What sort of behaviour could cause a segmentation fault at memory allocation?  And how can I narrow down where this is occurring in my code?

Comment: What are the expected values of `map_size`?

Comment: There are hundreds of possible "scenarios" in which that could happen, do you really expect us to list all of them? What have you tried so far? Using any kind of the many available debuggers?

Comment: The [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) tool will probably be of use to you if you run Mac or Linux. It detects this kind of memory errors and tells you where the offending lines of code are.

Comment: If you're absolutely positive it's that line that's causing the crash, the only problem with it can be `map_size`.

Comment: map_size is definitely not the issue.  If I replace it with the expected value "513".  The crash still occurs.

Answer (score 4):

Crashes calling memory allocation function are almost always due to corruption of the heap.

Think about how a memory allocation function works.  It first checks a list of previously freed blocks to see if there's one of an appropriate size, and if none is found it asks for a new block from the OS.

If some other code has trashed the heap's internal pointers by **writing beyond the bounds of some other dynamically allocated object**, then when the memory allocation function used by `::operator new` tries to walk the heap, it will use a wild pointer and crash.

The crash occurs here, but the memory corruption occurred earlier, and could literally be *anywhere* in your program that works with dynamically allocated objects.  It doesn't even have to be where the allocation or deallocation takes place.

Check whether your compiler provides "malloc debugging" which adds extra canary fields to the heap metadata surrounding dynamic allocations, in order to detect writes beyond the bounds.  Something like [Electric Fence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_Fence) (free!) can also help, by arranging for an unreachable page of memory to separate the metadata from every object, so the MMU traps the bounds error.  Or a runtime bounds checker along the lines of Rational Purify (really really expensive).

Comment: Very likely correct, on Windows I'd run that program straight through AppVerifier to catch the earlier corruption.  I'm not sure what tools are available on other platforms for this kind of thing.

Comment: @Benj: Which particular AppVerifier option is used?  There's one specifically for Heap Debugging, right?

Comment: Thanks!  I will check elsewhere in my code to see if I can find the offending code.

Comment: @Ben: Yes the page heap option is the one.  It put's each allocation in it's own page I believe and then fills what you don't use with a guard pattern.  If you stray into any memory that doesn't belong to your allocation, your program immediately crashes.

Comment: @Benj: A guard pattern doesn't actually cause an immediate crash, but it does narrow it down lots.  That's the canary field I mentioned.  Electric Fence goes a step further and actually reserves an extra page of address space, doing the equivalent of `VirtualProtect` to block read, write, and execution.  And that *does* crash the program right where the corruption first occurs.  options to Electric Fence allow you to align objects to either the top or bottom of the page, to catch overrun of front or back of the object.

Comment: I'm currently working in linux, but everything should compile in windows once setup.  I'll try and see if I can get valgrind to help me first and if not shift to windows for a bit and try AppVerifier.

Comment: @BenVoigt The guard pattern is just there to catch very small overruns I believe which don't run into the protected area.  It's explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220938(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Benj: Ok, that looks like exactly the same method as Electric Fence uses.

Comment: @Benj: Thanks you were correct.  I had another bit of code that was corrupting the heap.  I managed to catch it with Valgrind.